# how to implement an opening_time model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to implement an opening time mode for a store.

currently i have

```
Class Store
  has_one :opening_table

  #return opening_times as an array
  def opening_times
    self.build_opening_table unless opening_table
    (0..6).collect{ |i| 
      [opening_table.read_attribute("open_#{i}"),opening_table.read_attribute("close_#{i}") ]
    }      
  end

  def opening_times=(attr)
    self.build_opening_table unless opening_table
    i=0
    attr.each do |el|
      opening_table.attributes= {"open_#{i}".to_sym => el[0]}
      opening_table.attributes= {"close_#{i}".to_sym => el[1]}
      i=i+1
    end
 end
```

and OpeningTable has fields open_0, close_0 for monday opening and closing time

```
 create_table :opening_tables do |t|
  t.references :advertisement, :null=>false
  (0..6).each do |i|
    t.integer "open_#{i}"
    t.integer "close_#{i}"
  end
  t.timestamps
end
```

i dont feel comfortable and flexible with this solution but i dont have an idea to implement it in a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make another table called `Schedule`

```
create_table :schedules do |t|
   t.integer 'open'
   t.integer 'close'
   t.integer store_id
   t.timestamps
end
```

And then make the store `has _many :schedules`

So you can acces `Store.first.schedules[0].open` And so on.

EDIT:
For the nested attribute, you would simply access through the `store.schedules[0]`

or you could add to the `schedules` table:

```
t.string :week_day
```

and then do `store.schedules.find_by_week_day("monday")`

As for the validation, add that to your models/store.rb

```
validate :has_seven_schedules
...
def has_seven_schedules
   self.schedules.count == 7 ? true : false
end
```

EDIT2:

If you wanted you could put that `find_by_week_day("monday")` on a method inside the store.rb model like:

```
def opening_time(day)
   schedule = self.schedules.find_by_week_day(day)
   unless schedule.nil?
       return schedule.open
   end
end
```

And the same for the closing_time.

Comment: well, i had that idea also, but how to do with exactly 7 days, means it needs to have 7 childrens of schedules. and how to make that as a nested attribute?

Comment: i will bounty it for 150 :P

Comment: well, the has_many makes it a nested attribute, as for the exactly 7 days see my edit.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4513357 thats my current code. but how to make it nested, especially for an json api call?
how can i bring in a set of weekdays with opening times? thats too difficult for me. i want something like a call on api/advertisements/1 with data like {advertisement:{opening_times:{monday: {12,20}, tuesday: {12,19}}} but i dont know how to bring that in the controller that the key of the opening_time is the weekday. hope u know what i mean

Comment: okay, i can set day by day with this a.opening_time(:monday).update_attributes open: 12, close: 14

Comment: yes, you can change that `self.opening_times.build weekday: weekday` to `self.opening_times.create(weekday: weekday, open: x, close: y)`

Comment: appreciated. maybe you can help me with doing the api call. i dont get it, how to send data with the model by api, that its saved automatically. damnit. my skype: gashipashi

Comment: I'll help you, you're added